# Basic AM,GM,HM Inequality problem

Tags: inequality

Prove that $a/(a-b+c) + b/(a-c+b) +c/(b+c-a) \leq 3$ if $a,b,c$ are positive integers using AM-GM-HM or otherwise .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**:If $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle, then the inequality is reversed.  $x = a-b+c, y = a-c+b, z = b+c-a$, then $x+y+z = a+b+c$, and $a = \dfrac{x+y}{2}$, $b = \dfrac{y+z}{2}$, and $c = \dfrac{z+x}{2}$,and using AM-GM we can get the $LHS \geq RHS$.

The inequality is **false** for $a = b = 3, c = 1$.